# ATL complains about not including Windows after VS2012 -> VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017, atl

I'm currently update our projects from VS2012 to VS2017. This has led one project to crash and moan in compilation about ATL.

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(450): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '__stdcall'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(450): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '__stdcall'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(450): error C2059: syntax error: '__stdcall'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(450): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(451): error C2065: 'PFNMOVEFILETRANSACTED': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(451): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'pfMoveFileTransacted'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(451): error C2065: 'pfMoveFileTransacted': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(451): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetProcAddress'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(453): error C2065: 'pfMoveFileTransacted': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(455): error C2065: 'pfMoveFileTransacted': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(571): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '__stdcall'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(571): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '__stdcall'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(571): error C2059: syntax error: '__stdcall'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(571): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(572): error C2065: 'PFNFINDFIRSTFILETRANSACTED': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(572): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'pfFindFirstFileTransacted'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(572): error C2065: 'pfFindFirstFileTransacted': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(572): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetProcAddress'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(574): error C2065: 'pfFindFirstFileTransacted': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(576): error C2065: 'pfFindFirstFileTransacted': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(576): error C2065: 'FindExInfoStandard': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(576): error C2065: 'FindExSearchNameMatch': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(175): error C2065: 'COINIT_MULTITHREADED': undeclared identifier
1>Done building project "MyProj.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

With error lines such as "undeclared identifier" refers to headers in the windows.h library.

When I include I include through a StdAfx.h which has;

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
```

Regardless where I put Windows.h, the error occurs. I find it likely that it is generated by `_WIN32_WINNT`stuff but all of that "should" work. Is it deprecated? I don't know... Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe its related to this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/050d38dd-2b49-49e3-884a-fdf2fe31f21c/unable-to-compile-in-2010-after-converting-2008-vc-solution?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: Syntax errors like this are only easy to explain if the SDK install is pretty messed up.  Not just one file, at least wtypes.h and objbase.h.  You need to do the "hello world" first, create a Win32 console mode app that #includes those two headers.  If it fails too then you have a bad SDK, if not then the /showIncludes compile option becomes useful.  Do note that you also don't seem to have `_UNICODE` #defined, not very healthy in a ATL project.  I can't be sure, this tools version is pretty new and I've avoided keeping vs2017 updated.

Comment: I had it defined already but I "forced" it and put the declarations just before the includes and it worked. So something, somewhere it must've changed. Just one remaining error though. C1017 invalid integer constant expression inside sdkddkver.h line 272.

Comment: Getting the #defines for `WINVER` or `_WIN32_WINNT` wrong can certainly cause a lot of havoc.  You'd better check all of your macaroni.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case there were multiple project including each others stdafx.h headers. This caused the macros to fail/corrupt. Sorting that out and using correct values of WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT fixed it all.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Alexander's answer make sure that you do NOT define the following:

`#define NOTEXTMETRIC`